# Dificuldade em conectar projetos VB6 com o Banco de Dados em usando Availability Group Listener na connection string

Tags: sql-server, visual-basic-6

Nosso cenário esta usando banco de dados MSSQL configurado para Alta Disponibilidade e foi criado Listener para fazer o link do balanceamento entre as instancias. 
Algumas aplicações feitas em projetos Asp.Net MVC conseguimos fazer conexão mudando o Web config e aplicando um usuário no IIS.

Exemplo do Web.config que funciona:

```
<add name="ContextEntities" connectionString="Data Source=tcp:AGListener,60236;Initial Catalog=ClienteDB;persist security info=True;integrated security=true;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Como fazer essa conexão nos projetos em VB6?

Exemplo de como está hoje no VB6:

```
Set cnBD = New ADODB.Connection
cnBD.CommandTimeout = 0
        With cnBD
             .Provider = "SQLOLEDB"
             .ConnectionString = "USER ID=USUARIO;password=P@SSW0RD; data source = ClienteServer;Initial catalog = ClienteDB"
             .Open
        End With
```

Comment: em `vb` também pode usar o `integrated security=true`, serão usadas as credenciais do usuário que está executando a aplicação em `vb`

Comment: Seria interessante, mas teria que criar as credencias de todos os usuários na instancia do sql server?

Comment: pode ser mais simples que isso se os usuários estiverem logados no domínio do Windows. Pode adicionar os usuários a um grupo e dar permissão no SQL para esse grupo ao invés de cada usuário individualmente